# d3.select() Not Returning Anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, select

I'm relatively new to React and especially d3. I'm trying to write a d3 scale graph with a custom dictionary. Everything shows up except for the last section in which I'm using a d3.select to add an axis label to my graph. My render() method returns the html generated by draw graph, as shown below.

```
 render(){
    return this.drawGraph();
  }

drawGraph(){
    return(
      <svg viewBox={`0 0 ${this.width} ${this.height}`} style={{maxWidth: `${this.width}px`, font: "10px sans-serif"}}>
        <g fill="steelblue">
          ${this.fruits.map(d =>
            <svg key={d.name}>
              <rect y={this.y(d.name)} x={this.x(0)} width={this.x(d.count) - this.x(0)} height={this.y.bandwidth()}></rect>
            </svg>)}
        </g>
        <g fill="white" textAnchor="end" transform={`translate(-6,${this.y.bandwidth()/2})`}>
          ${this.fruits.map(d =>
            <svg key={d.name}>
            <text y={this.y(d.name)} x={this.x(d.count)} dy="0.35em">{d.count}</text>
          </svg>)}
        </g>
        <g transform={`translate(0, ${this.margin.top})`}>
          {d3.select('g')
            .call(d3.axisLeft(this.y))
            .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
            .node()}
        </g>
    </svg>    
    );
  }
```

Can anyone tell me why the d3.select() clause returns as empty? Why can't it find the  block that it's inside and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `d3.select(‘g’)` inside *g tag*. That’s why it’s empty. Try to call it in `componentDidMount()` (for components) or in `useEffect` hook (for functions).

Comment: Thank you! This solved it. I moved my 'g' definition to `componentDidMount()` by appending it to my svg. My code looks like this now within componentDidMount.
`d3.select('svg').append('g').attr('transform', \`translate(0,${this.margin.top})\`).call(d3.axisTop(this.x)).call(g => g.select(".domain").remove()).node();`